# How to consistently increase or decrease the volume of a chosen harmonic frequency

Tags: vocals, frequency, instruments, spectrogram, harmonics

For the following instrument, I need to change the volume of one harmonic, where its frequency is not static. Please see the image for example. If I wanted to give Number 3 a +6dB boost, I could not be using standard equalizers and filters as the harmonic goes up and down in frequency, and the parameters in these tools are all static.

[image: figure]

I cannot set it to be a range either because as the clip plays sometimes as 1 (the fundamental) goes up in frequency, 2 goes into the set range and 3 goes out of this range.

How can I change the volume of a particular harmonic and have the change follow the harmonic itself, regardless of what frequency it fluctuates to?

Answer (score 2):

By utilizing a pitch tracker to follow the base frequency of the target sound, then using that info to drive the frequency of a peak filter after the appropriate multiplier.

Comment: could you explain in a little more detail please? How do I put this to practice in e.g. Adobe Audition? What plug-ins do I need? (I have upvoted you but it doesn't display because I don't have enough Reputation points)

Comment: @aspiringSoundDesigner your query implies you may need to study a number of the fundamentals. But please feel free to ask additional questions about pitch tracking plugins etc

Comment: what are some of the pitch trackers and peak filters I could use? I did a search nothing relevant turned up.

Comment: if this is to be done using 2 different plug-ins, how do I feed tracking data from the first one to the second one? which two plug-ins on the market would you suggest i use, which can swap data between them like this